# How should I hide/show div from script when using Bootstrap 4's new display classes

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-4

I have a div that on page load is hidden. Using BS4, I'm accomplishing this with the d-none class. This works great and I do understand the responsive display classes in BS4. My issue is that I can't show/hide this div from script as I normally would because of the !important on the display: none !important; definition of d-*.

Using jQuery's show/hide/toggle does not work because it does not override the !important. I"m left (seemingly) with 3 options.

1. Leave the div in the HTML rendered and then hide it in document load
   or
2. Use jQuery's (or similar) add/remove Class functions to add or remove the d-none.
   or
3. Define a .hidden class in my own stylesheet to make display work like BS3.

Neither of these options seem great. Both seem to be making one framework fight the other. Am I missing something? I like the BS4 display classes, but I can't imagine there isn't a better way to toggle them other then adding or removing them which could get tedious if there are multiple classes in use for responsiveness.

Here is an example of the relevant parts of my page:

HTML:

```
<html>
<body style="margin:20px;">
<form action="">
<input type="radio" name="cotype" id="1" value="D"> <label for="1">Distributor</label><br />
<input type="radio" name="cotype" id="2" value="ID"> <label for="2">Intl Distributor</label><br />
<input type="radio" name="cotype" id="3" value="S"> <label for="3">Supplier</label><br />
<input type="radio" name="cotype" id="4" value="IS"> <label for="4">Intl Supplier</label><br />
<br />
<div id="messagewrapper" class="hidden">
This should show for domestic companies.
</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Javascript:

```
function updateMessage() {
    var cotype = $('input[name=cotype]:checked').val();
  var message = $('#messagewrapper');
  if (cotype === 'D' || cotype === 'S'){
    message.show();
    } else {
    message.hide();
  }
}
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input').on('change', updateMessage);
});
```

Here is a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6j08ouk4/16/). If you choose a domestic company type, a message should show.

Answer (score 0):

Should be call the function looks like

```
function updateMessage() {
   var cotype = $('input[name=cotype]:checked').val();
   var message = $('#messagewrapper');
   if (cotype === 'D' || cotype === 'S'){
         message.addClass('custom-show');
   } else {
       message.removeClass('custom-show');
  }
}
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('#messagewrapper').hide();
    $('input').on('change', function (){
       updateMessage();
  });
});
```

Css

```
.custom-show{display:block !important;}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/6j08ouk4/30/

Comment: no, this won't help. The issue is that show and hide from jQuery aren't able to override the d-* classes from Bootstrap 4. If your thought was to not use the d-* class from Bootstrap and hide the div with the first line of your code, that won't work as written because updateMessage will only be called when an input changes, thus the message would be shown when the page first displays.

Comment: So instead of show hide through js add remove a css class. And put the css on your custom css file.

Comment: Or remove hidden class form it then hide it on ready event first.